# Is there a way to use dynamic SQL in a view?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have 5 tables and view pairs.

Example:

- Table `dynamics.Customer` (100 columns)
- View `staging.CustomerView` (20 columns)

The `CustomerView` is built from `staging.Customer` table and other staging tables, not `dynamics.Customer`.

I want to compare all rows with all fields that exists in `staging.CustomerView` to `dynamics.Customer` to see if changes has occurred to staging. I want this to show as a column in my `staging.CustomerView`.

Since I have 5 tables and view pairs I tried to create a function with dynamic SQL that got all rows from staging view and compare it to dynamics table. Then I called that function from each view. I got an error executing the function, as it used `sp_executesql`.

Is there a way to create a function that dynamically gets each column and compares it? The view is used in Azure Data Factory to Copy data into Dynamics365 and because of performance, I only want to insert/update the rows that has changed.

Comment: whats the reason for needing dynamic SQL inside a view?

Comment: There is no way to use dynamic SQL in a view, to answer the question in the title. Can't be done. Same for functions.

Answer (score 0):

Views are strongly typed, and cannot be created dynamically.

you can write trigger which records changes to another log table on updates and query that table.